# I can't add a UIPickerview for gender in a registration form

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am creating a registration form and I have to include the gender inside a text field using a picker view. However, I am getting question marks instead of male and female.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var genderfield: UITextField!

let pickerView = UIPickerView()
let gender1 = ["Male", "Female"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return gender1.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return gender1[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView:UIPickerView,didSelectRow row: Int,forComponent component: Int){
    genderfield.text = gender1[row]
    genderfield.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

And in ViewDidLoad:

```
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
genderfield.inputView = pickerView
```

I don't think there is something wrong in my code. I have been googling for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You get question marks because you have the wrong signature on your `titleForRow` delegate method.

Change:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return gender1[row]
}
```

to:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return gender1[row]
}
```

Note the addition of `_` just after the `(`.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the updated `titleForRow` method, is it being called?

Comment: I still see the same question marks so its  not being called

Comment: Again, using the debugger, can you verify whether `numberOfRowsInComponent` is being called. If that returns a non-zero result, verify whether `titleForRow` is being called or not. Actually verify in the debugger. Also confirm that you are using Swift 3 or later.

Comment: these 2 methods are not being called.And I am using swift 4

Comment: If neither are being called then the picker view's delegate and dataSource are not set. I know the code you posted indicates that they are set but if they were, these methods would be called. There must be more going on than you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not added  UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource.
so when you add delegate and data source of picker view its work fine.

like this:
extension RegisterVC : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return gender1.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return gender1[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView:UIPickerView,didSelectRow row: Int,inComponent component: Int){
    genderfield.text = gender1[row]
    genderfield.resignFirstResponder()
}
```